# verify a list in a list match values of another list in python

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists (with tens of thousands of sub-lists).
In time more lists are added to the big list, by users.

As a mock example I have something similar:

```
my_list_grouped_by_0 = 
    [['X00001', 1123477, 1.25, 'Yes', 'No', 11.53, 3.23, 0.25], 
     ['X00002', 1125251, 0.22, 'Yes', 'No', 22.83, 3.6, 0.5], 
     ['X00003', 1125433, 1.23, 'Yes', 'No', 1.86, 3.65, 0.15], 
     ['X00004', 1231254, 1.3, 'Yes', 'No', 21.83, 3.6, 0.5], 
     ['X00008', 2520250, 54.02, 'Yes', 'No', 1.83, 3.8, 0.01], 
     ['X00005', 3202020, 966.33, 'Yes', 'No', 1.8, 3.8, 0.36], 
     ['X00006', 3215204, 1.36, 'Yes', 'No', 1.86, 3.65, 0.15], 
     ['X00007', 4561230, 6.33, 'Yes', 'No', 1.83, 66.22, 0.1], 
     ['X00009', 5721365, 1.25, 'No', 'No', 11.53, 3.23, 0.25], 
     ['X00010', 8520025, 6.33, 'Yes', 'No', 1.83, 66.22, 0.1], 
     ['X00012', 8520123, 966.33, 'Yes', 'No', 1.8, 3.8, 0.36], 
     ['X00011', 9536122, 54.01, 'Yes', 'No', 1.83, 3.8, 0.01], 
     ['X00015', 1212021, 0.333, 'No', 'No', 1.83, 3.8, 0.01], 
     ['X00013', 9654123, 4.1, 'No', 'No', 1.83, 3.8, 0.01], 
     ['X00014', 2021230, 1.23, 'Yes', 'No', 1.86, 3.65, 0.15], 
     ['X00017', 3322123, 1.23, 'Yes', 'Yes', 1.88, 1.25, 1.12], 
     ['X00016', 9531450, 23.15, 'Yes', 'Yes', 1.83, 3.25, 0.12], 
     ['X00020', 3625252, 1.23, 'Yes', 'No', 1.86, 3.65, 0.15], 
     ['X00018', 1205203, 1.87, 'Yes', 'No', 1.88, 1.25, 1.12], 
     ['X00019', 1124521, 0.25, 'No', 'No', 2.1, 0.6, 0.03], 
     ['X00021', 8952631, 0.25, 'No', 'No', 2.4, 0.6, 0.03], 
     ['X00022', 1123458, 0.33, 'Yes', 'Yes', 10.38, 41.11, 0.5], 
     ['X00023', 3236254, 3, 'No', 'Yes', 10.38, 41.11, 0.5], 
     ['X00024', 1205323, 1.87, 'Yes', 'No', 1.88, 1.25, 1.12]]
```

users will add new lists such as:

```
['X00099', 1212021, 0.333, 'No', 'No', 1.83, 3.8, 0.01]
```

If the values at index 2,3,4,5,6,7 match with one of the lists in the existing list of list, I want the value at index 0 (in this case X00099) to be overwritten by the value that was in the original list of lists (in this case 'X00015', since values match).

In case the new list doesn't match any of the existing list, I want to add next X00000 value (in this case, to the newly added list I'll assign X00025.

The values at index 1 are an Id that is unique to each list and is used just to overwrite back information to database, confirming that the list with the respective Id is identical in values with other lists.

I do not know how to compare the newly added list with the lists in the original list of list and see if matches anything or is new.

However, I can use groupby:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
```

and get this:

```
>>> my_list_grouped_by = [list(g) for _, g in groupby(sorted(my_list), itemgetter(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7))]
>>> my_list_grouped_by
[[['X0000', 1123477, 1.25, 'Yes', 'No', 11.53, 3.23, 0.25]], 
[['X0000', 1125251, 0.22, 'Yes', 'No', 22.83, 3.6, 0.5]], 
[['X0000', 1125433, 1.23, 'Yes', 'No', 1.86, 3.65, 0.15]], 
[['X0000', 1231254, 1.3, 'Yes', 'No', 21.83, 3.6, 0.5]], 
[['X0000', 2520250, 54.02, 'Yes', 'No', 1.83, 3.8, 0.01]], 
[['X0000', 3202020, 966.33, 'Yes', 'No', 1.8, 3.8, 0.36]], 
[['X0000', 3215204, 1.36, 'Yes', 'No', 1.86, 3.65, 0.15]], 
[['X0000', 4561230, 6.33, 'Yes', 'No', 1.83, 66.22, 0.1], 
['X0000', 5252631, 6.33, 'Yes', 'No', 1.83, 66.22, 0.1]], 
[['X0000', 5721365, 1.25, 'No', 'No', 11.53, 3.23, 0.25], 
['X0000', 7721365, 1.25, 'No', 'No', 11.53, 3.23, 0.25]], 
[['X0000', 8520025, 6.33, 'Yes', 'No', 1.83, 66.22, 0.1]], 
[['X0000', 8520123, 966.33, 'Yes', 'No', 1.8, 3.8, 0.36]], 
[['X0000', 9536122, 54.01, 'Yes', 'No', 1.83, 3.8, 0.01]], 
[['X0010', 1212021, 0.333, 'No', 'No', 1.83, 3.8, 0.01]], 
[['X0010', 9654123, 4.1, 'No', 'No', 1.83, 3.8, 0.01]], 
[['X0020', 2021230, 1.23, 'Yes', 'No', 1.86, 3.65, 0.15]], 
[['X0070', 3322123, 1.23, 'Yes', 'Yes', 1.88, 1.25, 1.12]], 
[['X0070', 9531450, 23.15, 'Yes', 'Yes', 1.83, 3.25, 0.12]], 
[['X0303', 3625252, 1.23, 'Yes', 'No', 1.86, 3.65, 0.15],
['X0333', 3625257, 1.23, 'Yes', 'No', 1.86, 3.65, 0.15]], 
[['X0670', 1205203, 1.87, 'Yes', 'No', 1.88, 1.25, 1.12]], 
[['X1070', 1124521, 0.25, 'No', 'No', 2.1, 0.6, 0.03], 
['X1070', 3302145, 0.25, 'No', 'No', 2.1, 0.6, 0.03]], 
[['X1070', 8952631, 0.25, 'No', 'No', 2.4, 0.6, 0.03]], 
[['X3330', 1123458, 0.33, 'Yes', 'Yes', 10.38, 41.11, 0.5]], 
[['X3330', 3236254, 3, 'No', 'Yes', 10.38, 41.11, 0.5]], 
[['X8670', 1205323, 1.87, 'Yes', 'No', 1.88, 1.25, 1.12]]]
>>>
```

Then I can loop through and overwrite X00000 with the one from the first member of the group, but that will not guarantee that the X00000 will be one from the existing list of list.

And keeping the original X number is essential to this task.

Any suggestions or point out to similar solutions, greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much for looking and help!

Answer (score 0):

You could create an index (similar to a DB index) of the relevant columns and use it for lookup.

With some pseudo-code this can look like this:

```
indexed = {tuple(entry[2:8]): idx for idx, entry in enumerate(my_list_grouped_by_0)}

def add_new(newEntry):
    col0 = indexed.get(tuple(newEntry[2:8]))

    if col0 is None:
        <Assign new id to col0>

    my_list_grouped_by_0.append([col0] + newEntry[1:])

    <Add new entry to index if necessary>
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying your solution, however I'm getting an error for global variable that is not defined. I do not know how to change the "entry" to a global so it will be ok inside of the function. Could you please point out to how I overcome that issue. Below is the error. I cannot post the entire script as the posts are limited here. Thank you very much for your help!  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in add_new
NameError: global name 'entry' is not defined

Comment: @alc I mixed entry and newEntry. I have corrected my code.

Comment: @ Michael Butscher - thank you. I tweaked the code and I have something that is working. Now I need to scale it up for very large lists of lists. There is an issue with this line my_list_grouped_by_0.append([col0] + newEntry[1:])  as should be changed to my_list_grouped_by_0.append(newEntry) this way I'm adding the new list with the newly assigned id to the existing list. col0 is pulling the found/not found index (so in this case is None). please correct me if I'm wrong, but I tested the code with modified line and it is working. thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

The intuitive solution would be to use a generator comprehension and list slicing like so:

```
new = ['X00025', 8520025, 6.33, 'Yes', 'No', 1.83, 66.22, 0.1]  # same as X00010

new[1:] in (elem[1:] for elem in my_list_grouped_by_0))  # returns True because of X00010
```

However if performance is important, I can't guarantee the relative speed of this solution.

**Edit:**

This would be an example of a function that not just checks for matches but also does the updating.

```
def add_to_big_list(new):
    for old in my_list_grouped_by_0:
        if new[1:] == old[1:]:
            # A match was found so we replace the ID.
            old[0] = new[0]
            return
    # No match was found so we add the new entry.
    my_list_grouped_by_0.append(new)
```